# Sql Server DB causes huge disk QUEUE and outages of service.

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, health-monitoring, sql-server-profiler

I'm facing this situation, and need some advise as to how approach this.

From time to time, usually out of business hours, but it's most likely random, the activity on a database we host goes out of scale.
This means that the disk queue grows from accepted levels (below 2) to crazy and sustained values, for example the last incident queue went to an average of 450 for 30 minutes.

[image: a slice of the recorded performance activity]

Cases are not always this exaggerate, and maybe this makes it easier to spot than the more subtle cases.

When this happens, it causes services depending on the DB to go down / error out / timeout, etc.

I can see it and record it on perfmon, I know it's read-queue (at least last incident), I know it's focused on a high activity SQL SERVER DB stored exclusively on that disk, but I can't pin-point the exact cause.

I have tried collecting data with profiler, but this tends to happen:
- I monitor query durations (3 secs or more), looking for rogue queries with bad execution plans. 
- If lucky enough to witness one of these incidents, I will see mostly any query being captured, which really means that the server is slowed down, and even good queries are taking long because something else is going on.

I believe query duration is not what I have to chase down, so maybe you could help me figure out how else to approach this ? It's a process doing something, a query, a maintenance task, a backup, anything, that is causing massive IO on the disk. Although I don't really believe it's a query alone, it looks too aggressive as to be that.

Sql Server logs do not show errors, neither point to something that could help troubleshooting this. Maintenance activities, some of them have logs, other don't generate logs, which is yielding to equivocal interpretations.

So, what are the events that I should hook onto profiler to spot the cause of these incidents ? 
What else can I do, without turning to a paid tool, to pin-point the activity that sql server starts doing, at random times, that cause disk queue to build up, ultimately going out of scale and causing service downages.

I turn to SO as last resource, believe me, I have been studying this and looking for ideas, and tried more than a few things, but I just have to admit I failed and look for your advise.

Thank you !

Comment: What do your wait stats look like overall?  Do you have any other waits that are spiking that are not related to disk activity?  We monitor waits with a task every 3 minutes and this helps pinpoint some issues like this.  At least it gives us more information to eliminate some things.

Comment: Could you elaborate this on an answer of its own ? I don't monitor on waits, how do you monitor waits in the way you describe ? Thanks :)

Comment: Start here.  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: Is this on a VM? Any chance this server is under provisioned and it's not getting the RAM that it thinks it is? What are your RAM settings? IS your SQL Server limited to 2-4G under total server RAM? There are ways to find out if it is a memory pressure issue.